# Adding the ability to inline Gist code snippets from GitHub

Tags: feature-request, code

It should be pretty straight forward to add the following code snippets to the allowed HTML subset, or some additional markup that would effectively do the same thing.

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/839992.js?file=Switch.java"></script>
```

so that the above would display the nice formatted, line numbered, code folded display that GitHub provides inline as a code block.

Comment: I think this would be great for a few more reasons: - people are already posting links to github (this would allow more control and would show when it is well used)- allow sourcing of the raw code directly (no more copy pasting) - when the code gets updated (for example to allow compatibility to upgrades) the question get updated automaticly - you could probably still have a line limit -the solution may spread through the net faster - you could maybe get github to have a specific stack overflow tag/gist type -...

Comment: Not to mention how easy it would be to clone the code of the question, fiddle with it and push a fork to link to in the response. You could then even build upon other responders forks to improve existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

This already happens in chat (paste it as a single link on a single message), but I don't think we need to support it here for two reasons

1. The relevant bits of code should be in the post for context, otherwise the question / answer is incomplete.
2. If you need to say "and there's 50kb more code to look at [here](http://example.com)", then a link suffices for that purpose.

Comment: Couldn't line limits still be imposed to the gist script?  How to deal with frequent required update of answers du to changes in related structure, data, script...?

Comment: Sometimes a nicely formatted gist with around 10 lines could really do the trick, inline. How about a cutoff at around 10 lines?