# Suggested edit moved JSON data to gist at GitHub

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/937216) moved JSON data from the post to a gist at GitHub.

Is this an appropriate edit?

With code inline, the question initially contained relevant JSON data inline to the question.  Per a comment asking whether the JSON was the full response, indicating it was invalid JSON, the OP updated the question with full JSON response.

Although significant, the JSON data is not overwhelming.  It is relevant as the focus of the question is parsing the data.  Now, this context is dependent on this gist being maintained.

Per [Adding the ability to inline Gist code snippets from GitHub](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80679/adding-the-ability-to-inline-gist-code-snippets-from-github) question at GitHub, Jeff Atwood states:

> 1. The relevant bits of code should be in the post for context, otherwise the question / answer is incomplete.
> 2. If you need to say "and there's 50kb more code to look at here", then a link suffices for that purpose.

Per [Is it okay to link to gist code pastes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/is-it-okay-to-link-to-gist-code-pastes), ЯegDwight states:

> I would post all (relevant!) code in the question body, for at least
>   two reasons:
>
> 1. People can have a good overview of my problem right away and dive into my code directly rather than repeatedly clicking back and forth.
> 2. The code might also include some additional search terms, which is good for future users with a similar problem, or for SEO in general.

So, should data remain inline to the question?

Perhaps only the original relevant JSON segment should be retained?

Comment: Note that the mobile site has no scrollbars. That is a very long post on mobile...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've rolled that back.

While I don't feel that *all* of that should be in there, it's even worse to have *none* of it in there and just a link to on an external site (for all the reasons we don't like relying too heavily on links).

That edit should have never been approved.

The OP should be notified that he should isolate the JSON returned to highlight the source of his problem.